# How to display a string inside a list as individual elements

Tags: python

```
data = [
    [',Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday'],
    ['8,1,1,0,1,1,0,0'], ['9,0,0,1,0,0,1,0'], ['10,0,0,1,0,0,1,0'],
    ['11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'],
    ['14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['16,0,0,0,1,0,2,3'],
    ['17,1,1,2,0,1,1,0'], ['18,1,0,0,2,1,1,2']
]
```

I have this data of nested lists. However this data inside the nested lists are seen as one big string, like this

```
[',Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday']
```

etc, but I want the data to display like this instead

```
["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
```

etc, so I can access the information by indexing. And I want to do this which all of the nested lists.
However not quite sure how to do this or even how to start, I guess could start of by looping through, but then seperate it into elements seems to be the hard part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, there's only 1 value inside each inner list:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0].split(","), data))
```

Comment: Clean solution, although maybe the case of ```[',Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday'] ``` should be handled by removing the resulting_innerlist[0] if it is an empty String!

Comment: Maybe you should also add `.strip(',')`? Because the first string starts with a comma

Comment: i think this is the best way to do it, but as @LukasKaspras pointed out, you need to remove the first innerSting, maybe using list[0].pop(0) after running the function above.

Comment: All other strings have 8 values per string, thus I'm not sure if it should be removed

Comment: yeah good point! not sure then, maybe OP can clarify!

Comment: Oh, now I see! The first value in all other InnerLists increases by 1 from InnerList to InnerList. Maybe it stands for the Week of the Year; maybe it is just an index; whatever it is, you can transform the empty string in the first InnerList into "Week of Year" or "Index" so that the whole InnerList would look like: ```["Week of Year", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]```. Afterwards you could also generate a pandas dataframe from this list; and take the first InnerList as header! (A lot of maybe's here)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) and the `.split()` method.

```py
x = [item[0].split(",") for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
data = [[',Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday'],
        ['8,1,1,0,1,1,0,0'],
        ['9,0,0,1,0,0,1,0'],
]

# Split the sublists on a comma:
data = [s.split(',') for sublist in data for s in sublist]

# Clean up the first sublist: remove the leading empty string: 
data[0] = [s for s in data[0] if s]

# Clean up the rest of the sublists: convert string to integer:
data[1:] = [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in data[1:]]

print(data)
# [['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'], [8, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```